# ffmpeg concatenation after using drawtext filter

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm fairly new to ffmpeg, but after a few days of searching on this issue, I've completely hit a brick wall. Any help would be appreciated.

My use case: Our client wants to upload videos for multiple regions. Each video will be the same format, 1920x1080, mp4. For each region, they want to add a different image at the end of the video, for a few seconds. This image contains their logo, some additional info, and a variable code. They will enter this code alongside the uploaded video. The image stays the same, so is already present on the server.
So basically, I have an input video, a video of an image, and a small code. I need to add this code to the video of the image (in a predefined position), and then I need to add the resulting video to the end of the input video. Once that is complete, I just need to output the video in 1920x1080 and in 1024x576.

I have tried several things, but the concatenation step always fails with the manipulated video's.

**Attempt 1**

In my first attempt, I used ffmpeg to create a video from an image, and add the text in the designated area.

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i image.png -r 30 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:v -vf drawtext="fontfile=HelveticaNeue.dfont: text='GLNS/TEST/1234b': fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=7: x=179: y=805" imageVideo.mp4
```

This command creates a .mp4 video of the correct size, with a duration of 10 seconds, and adds the text 'GLNS/TEST/1234b' in the correct location.

Next, I use the following command to concatenate the two videos. Both have the same resolution and codec.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i config.txt -vf scale=1920:1080 outputHD.mp4 -vf scale=1024:576 outputSD.mp4
```

*config.txt* contains following:

```
file my_input_file.mp4
file ImageVideo.mp4
```

This concatenation works with regular videos. However, when I use it with ImageVideo.mp4 (the one created by the first command) I get this error log:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f86dc924600] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filtereed=0.509x    
[aac @ 0x7f86dc019e00] Number of bands (31) exceeds limit (5).
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 0x7f86dc019e00] Number of bands (27) exceeds limit (8).
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 0x7f86dd857200] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x7f86dd829400] Invalid NAL unit size.
[h264 @ 0x7f86dd829400] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[aac @ 0x7f86dc019e00] Number of bands (10) exceeds limit (1).
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 0x7f86dd816800] Invalid NAL unit size.
[h264 @ 0x7f86dd816800] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[aac @ 0x7f86dc019e00] Number of bands (24) exceeds limit (1).
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input

#this goes on for a few hundred lines
```

The resulting output is identical to the input video, but does not contain the desired image video at the end.

**Attempt 2**

Since the above attempt didn't work, I tried concatenating a video I let our designer make of the image with Adobe After Effects. This video was also saved as a .mp4 with the H264 codec. If I concatenate the input video and this one, I get a correct result. However, as soon as I add the code in the designated area with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i new_image_video.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=HelveticaNeue.dfont: text='GLNS/TEST/1234b': fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=7: x=179: y=805" -c:v libx264 imageVideo.mp4
```

I get this error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7ff94c800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter97x    
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053800] top block unavailable for requested intra mode -1
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053800] error while decoding MB 0 0, bytestream 49526
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] number of reference frames (1+3) exceeds max (3; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] chroma_log2_weight_denom 28 is out of range
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] illegal long ref in memory management control operation 2
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] cabac_init_idc 32 overflow
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053800] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b072a00] reference overflow 22 > 15 or 0 > 15
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b072a00] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b072a00] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b01a400] illegal modification_of_pic_nums_idc 20
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b01a400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b01a400] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b01aa00] illegal modification_of_pic_nums_idc 20
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b01aa00] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b01aa00] no frame!
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053800] deblocking_filter_idc 8 out of range
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053800] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053800] no frame!
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] illegal memory management control operation 8
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] error while decoding MB 2 0, bytestream -35
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b053e00] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in B frame
[h264 @ 0x7ff94b072a00] number of reference frames (1+3) exceeds max (3; probably corrupt input), discarding one

# this goes on for a while...

[h264 @ 0x7ff94b01a400] concealing 4962 DC, 4962 AC, 4962 MV errors in B frame
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
frame= 2553 fps= 17 q=-1.0 Lsize=   26995kB time=00:01:42.16 bitrate=2164.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=60 speed=0.697x    
video:25258kB audio:1661kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.285236%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] frame I:35    Avg QP:17.45  size: 55070
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] frame P:711   Avg QP:19.73  size: 18712
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] frame B:1807  Avg QP:21.53  size:  5884
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] consecutive B-frames:  3.4%  5.0%  4.9% 86.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] mb I  I16..4: 38.2% 49.3% 12.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] mb P  I16..4: 12.4% 14.0%  1.0%  P16..4: 29.6%  4.8%  1.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:36.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] mb B  I16..4:  1.5%  1.2%  0.1%  B16..8: 27.3%  1.6%  0.1%  direct: 1.8%  skip:66.4%  L0:45.8% L1:51.4% BI: 2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] 8x8 transform intra:49.5% inter:85.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 21.2% 22.3% 2.5% inter: 4.6% 7.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 23% 26% 10% 41%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 19% 35%  3%  3%  3%  3%  3%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 20% 16%  5%  7%  6%  5%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 67% 16% 15%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:7.3% UV:4.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] ref P L0: 66.3%  8.7% 17.9%  7.0%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] ref B L0: 88.2% 10.1%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] ref B L1: 94.9%  5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff94b810400] kb/s:2026.12
[aac @ 0x7ff94b072400] Qavg: 635.626
```

The resulting output is identical to the input video, but does not contain the desired image video at the end.

One thing I have noticed: When I inspect the video files on mac (Get info) they always contain these lines at 'More info':

```
Dimensions: 1920 x 1080
Codecs: H.264, AAC
Color profile: HD(1-1-1)
Duration: 01:42
Audio channels: 2
Last opened: Today 11:02
```

However, the video's which pass through the drawtext filter have this:

```
Dimensions: 1920 x 1080
Codecs: AAC, H.264
Duration: 00:10
Audio channels: 2
Last opened: Today 11:07
```

As you can see, there is no color profile entry, and the codecs have switched places. I assume this is related to my issue, but I can't seem to find a fix for it.

PS: The application will run in a php environment (Symfony). I noticed the concat command wasn't available in the Symfony bundle for ffmpeg, so I'm using the regular terminal commands. I'll execute these using php.

EDIT
**Attempt 3**

On advise of a coworker, I tried converting the video to .avi and reconverting to .mp4, in the hopes this would lose any corrupted or extra info included by the drawtext filter. This spits out a completely different error.

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f812413da00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filtereed=0.516x    
[concat @ 0x7f8124009a00] DTS 1569260 < 2551000 out of order
[h264 @ 0x7f8124846800] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 0x7f8124846800] error while decoding MB 0 0, bytestream 47919
[h264 @ 0x7f8124846800] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in I frame
[aac @ 0x7f8125809a00] Queue input is backward in time
[aac @ 0x7f8125815a00] Queue input is backward in time
[h264 @ 0x7f8124846e00] number of reference frames (1+3) exceeds max (3; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x7f8124846e00] chroma_log2_weight_denom 26 is out of range
[h264 @ 0x7f8124846e00] deblocking_filter_idc 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x7f8124846e00] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8124846e00] no frame!
[mp4 @ 0x7f8124802200] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 4902912, current: 4505491; changing to 4902913. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x7f8125813000] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 1:1; previous: 4902912, current: 4505491; changing to 4902913. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[h264 @ 0x7f8124803400] reference overflow 20 > 15 or 0 > 15
[h264 @ 0x7f8124803400] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8124803400] no frame!
[mp4 @ 0x7f8124802200] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 4902913, current: 4506515; changing to 4902914. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x7f8125813000] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 1:1; previous: 4902913, current: 4506515; changing to 4902914. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x7f8124802200] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 4902914, current: 4507539; changing to 4902915. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x7f8125813000] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 1:1; previous: 4902914, current: 4507539; changing to 4902915. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

# Again, this continues for quite a while.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the concat filter instead, and do it in one command.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -loop 1 -framerate 30 -t 10 -i image.png 
       -filter_complex "[1]drawtext=fontfile=HelveticaNeue.dfont:text='GLNS/TEST/1234b':
                           fontcolor=black:fontsize=20:box=1:boxcolor=white:boxborderw=7:
                           x=179:y=805[it];
                        [0:v][it]concat,split[hd][sd]"
      -map "[hd]" -map 0:a combined1080p.mp4
      -map "[sd]" -map 0:a -s 1024x576 combined576p.mp4
```

I assume both your main video and image are already 1920x1080.

Comment: For the noobs between us, why does this work, but the other fails?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, worked like a charm. Had to remove the " after drawtext= though, that was a typo. And like vrwim asked, would you like to explain why this works and what was wrong?

Comment: I can't definitively debug your commands but the concat demuxer requires matching stream order and matching stream properties like codec, resolution, pixel format (though not colorspace) but also properties like timebase, 0-start PTS which apps like AE don't allow user to modify or which new FFmpeg users won't know to specify. Best to use concat demuxer when you are stitching segments generated from the same source.